# Xubuntu 12.10 : Can't add account to network application

Tags: networking, xubuntu, xfce, pidgin, gwibber

When I try to add an account to **Gwibber/Pidgin** (which are not system apps), it sends me to the **System parameters**. It is impossible for me to add accounts to these apps. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got this answer myself. 
you have to startup the settings like this

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

just pop this into a terminal window or into Alt+F2 and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it with pidgin, for me it works if you add the account by its 'buddy list', then via menu.

However, I can reproduce it with gwibber. It appears that gwibber is tied to the gnome framework which in turn needs gnome services running. However enabling them in the session properties has no effect.

You can configure empathy, which is almost the same, with `empathy-accounts` from the command line or the application launcher, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: I already use Empathy, but Pidgin was another example to prove that it was not only the problem of Gwibber.